# HTML input field of type Map

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have a model with some basic properties but also a property that is a map, like so

```
{
    "id": "...",
    "name": "...",
    "foo": {
        "apple": "pear",
        "dog": "cat",
        ...
    }
}
```

I am looking for the best way to create this from an HTML form, as well as fill an html form for viewing/editing, like so

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="id"/>
<input type="text" name="name"/>
...some input field(s) for "foo"...
</form>
```

Ideally I would also like to be able to perform client-side form validation to make sure that the map does not include duplicates, certain keys, certain values, etc...

I would also like the ability to add new key/value pairs and remove existing pairs.

The solution I have implemented so far is a table whose rows each include a key input field, value input field, and remove button, a separate button for adding new rows to the table, and a submit() method on the form that manually grabs all key/value pairs and builds the map, so it is a very manual assembly/population process.

```
<form>
    <table id="foo">
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="key"/><td>
    <td><input type="text" name="value"/><td>
    <td><input type="button" value="remove/><td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<script>
    $("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //loop through rows, get key/values, build JSON and submit
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Well, can you share what have you tried?

Comment: I added my approach to representing/building that data structure with javascript/html, and it is a very manual process. I am wondering if another method exists

Comment: Why don't you use a dropdown menu?

Comment: @Barmar do you mean a `<select>`? The select would not allow me to define key/value pairs, only a list of values

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I thought you wanted to validate that they were entering something in the map. Now I see that they're using the form to create the map.